# Find Image components using python/PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Is there a function in PIL/Pillow that for a grayscale image, will separate the image into sub images containing the components that make up the original image? For example, a png grayscale image with a set of blocks in them. Here, the images types always have high contrast to the background.

I don't want to use openCV, I just need some general blob detection, and was hoping Pillow/PIL might have something that does that already.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do? What do your images look like? You need to provide some additional information, ideally with some code examples of what you already tried

Comment: I'm asking specifically if there is function in PIL/Pillow that might perform this. I have made it clear I have no working code.

Comment: Well there is no magic `do_what_i_want()` function. You need to elaborate more. In general if you say you have good contrast then start by thresholding. A labelling algorithm like `floodfill` can identify different blobs and then you can just calculate the bounding box.

Comment: I used `from skimage.measure import label, regionprops` that allows you to construct something that will identify regions and label them with incrementing integers (the `array` has to be `boolean`, so you have to pick a threshold value to generate it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use `edge` detection algorithms in PIL.
Sample code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
image = Image.open('/tmp/sample.png').convert('RGB')
image = image.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
image.save('/tmp/output.png')
```

sample.png :

[image]

output.png:

[image]

Comment: How can OP extract the rectangles, when there are more? How would you identify a region where the rectangle was found?

Answer (score 0):

Not using PIL, but worth a look I think:
I start with a list of image files that I've imported as a list of `numpy` arrays, and I create a list of boolean versions where the `threshold` is `> 0`

```
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
import numpy as np

bool_array_list= []

for image in image_files:
    bool_array = np.copy(image)
    bool_array[np.where(bool_array > 0)] = 1
    bool_array_list.append(bool_array)

img_region_list = []
```

Then I use label to identify the different areas, using 8-directional connectivity, and `regionprops` gives me a bunch of metrics, such as size and location.

```
for item in bool_array_list:
    tmp_region_list = regionprops(label(item, 
                                        connectivity=2
                                       )
                                 )
    img_region_list.append(tmp_region_list)
```